# small signal analysis solve

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have found this small signal analysis circuit in my exercise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwKl5m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried both \$\pi\$-model and T-model but can't go anywhere. When trying to figure out \$V_o\$ can't decide whether take only \$R_L\$ or \$R_L\$  || \$(R_1 +R_2)\$ as DC current also flow through \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ .
For other parameters like \$V_{in} , R_{in} , R_{out} \$ can't even make any idea.

How can I  solve this and please,explain in detail so that in future I can solve this kind of circuits by myself. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Common Gate (common base for BJT) . http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/lectures/lecture_6/pdfs/lecture23.pdf Even though your grounds are different, the Common gate might lend understanding

Comment: I know about common gate.Here main problem is \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ . If only \$R_1\$ or \$R_2\$ exist then it will not draw any current and can be solved.As both exist at same time, It draws a sufficient amount of current and again for equivalent circuit , make confusing whether to use \$\pi\$-model or T-model.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the small-signal drain voltage is given by

$$v_d = -i_d R_L||(R_1 + R_2)$$

so that's all there is to that.

If this were a true common-gate circuit, the small-signal gate-source voltage would be

$$v_{gs} = v_g - v_s = 0 - v_{sig} = - v_{sig}$$

but, in this circuit, the gate is not at signal common so we have

$$v_{gs} = v_g - v_s = v_d \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} - v_{sig}$$

And, recalling that

$$i_d = g_mv_{gs}$$

you should have all you need to finish the problem.

Comment: when I tried to solve this problem, I manage to find \$V_d\$ though I was confused about the result. thnx for ensuring.
I mainly having trouble to find voltage gain \$ A_v \$ and \$ R_{in}\$

Comment: @Anklon, if you have \$v_d\$, you have all you need for the voltage gain.

Comment: What about \$V_{in}\$ ??
when I looked through any equivalent model either \$\pi\$ or T ,  It become confusing to say which part I'll consider as \$V_{in}\$.
Again other things also need to found like \$R_{in}\$ , \$ G_v\$

Comment: @Anklon, isn't \$v_{in}\$ just \$v_{sig}\$?

Comment: ops... due to exam's pressure I can't notice that.sorry
But what about \$R_{in}\$,\$R_{out}\$ & \$G_v\$??